# Submit Button to Perform Two different actions

Tags: javascript

I have the following code on my login page for Submit.

```
$("form").submit(function()
{setTimeout(function(){
alert("Thank you for requesting an account. Once your request is reviewed by an administrator, you will receive an email with your login credentials."); location.reload();
submit = true;}, 3000);
});
```

The issue is I have another Submit button, and this message pops up on clicking that button as well. How can i fix this?

I want one submit to show this popup and the other submit button  to login to the application without showing this popup.

Comment: can you please post relevant code??

Comment: bind the function to the button's click event, not the form submit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must not use `$("form")` because it will match **all form elements**.
You should assign an ID or class attribute to your forms so that you would match only those specific elements.

```
$("#form-id").submit(function() ...
   ^^^^^^^^
```

And your HTML form:

```
<form id="form-id">
```

Comment: @Rax...find my html code here...https://jsfiddle.net/ur974nex/.....

what should be my form ID...i tried various options but not getting the desired output...

Comment: @Rax..sorry silly question..where should i put this in my code ....<form id="form-id">

Comment: That is your existing html form. You just have to add `id="form-id"` to your form attributes.

Comment: No problem. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the alert on the submit of the form do it on the click of buttons and then call submit.

```
$( "#firstButton" ).click(function() {
alert('whatever');
  $( "#form_id" ).submit();
});

$( "#secondButton" ).click(function() {
  $( "#form_id" ).submit();
});
```

Also, to prevent the buttons within your form from automatically submitting change their types from type="submit" to type="button". This way they will not trigger the submit automatically. Instead you will only trigger the submit explicitly inside your click functions.

Answer (score 0):

use separate button IDs and call a function to submit the from. also provide unique ID for the form because using the form tag will trigger the submit function of all form elements

```
$('#buttonid').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   submitFunction(); }); // the function to submit the from with id #formID

function submitFunction(){
$("#formID").submit(function()
{setTimeout(function(){
alert("Thank you for requesting an account. Once your request is reviewed by an administrator, you will receive an email with your login credentials."); location.reload();
submit = true;}, 3000);
});
```

}